# Disable form field google script

Tags: google-forms

I have a link that leads to a prefilled Google form,  the prefilled form is editable and user can change the entries

I added a note not to change anything but of course user still has a capability to change it if they want to.

Is there a way to lock or restrict the user from editing the prefilled form?

The user need to see the fields with the prefilled content, but they should not be able to edit/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use prefilled values with a standard Google Form without allowing the user to edit those values in the form. Consider creating a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) based form instead of a standard Google Form. See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153205/269219) for sample code.

In the event the prefilled values do not need to be viewed or edited, you can put the fields that that hold them in a [section](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?ref_topic=9055304#zippy=%2Cadd-a-section) of their own. Then [skip that section](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062) so that it is not visible to people who fill in the form.

Comment: The user need to see the fields with the prefilled content, but they should not be able to edit/modify it.

Comment: Please include your requirements in the question instead of comments.